# help using google charts to overlay multiple graphs

Tags: php, google-visualization

Im having a little bit of difficulty trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

I have 3 sets of data. Each set of data consists of 30 numbers. These numbers have nothing to do with each other, and may be way out of scope of one another.

Here is an example set:

```
Set 1: 15,15,15,16,17,21,26,35,43
Set 2: 4,12,40,109,120,179,200,201
Set 3: 1004,1203,1476,2540,2784,3043
```

The problem, is that i need to graph the "performance" or range of increase of each set. Im thinking like a line graph showing visually how the numbers for the particular set increased, not compared to the other sets, but to itself. Basically a line graph with 1 line for 1 data set, 3 sets total, ignoring that one set may be vastly different than the next.

If anyone can help i would appreciate it, im kind of cloudy on exactly what this is called, so that may be hampering my search efforts. Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With two sets, you'd normally create a scale on both sides of the Y axis.  This way you can have totally different scales but will be able to compare lines.

I have a silly question though, if you have 3 unrelated data sets, (which appear to differ wildly in their min/max values) why are you wanting to graph them on the same graph?

It would make a lot more sense and make it much easier for your audience to understand the information you are trying to convey, if you had three different graphs.  Consider the example above with three lines, and three difference axes, (which will likely be different colours) to three seperate graphs, with different scales, and clearly labelled graph headings.

I know which one would be easier to understand. :)

EDIT: Sorry, I should also add that you can easily add three sets to a graph using Google images - however it is issue of scaling which you'll have trouble with.

Best of luck
Luke Peterson